# Program to use PDF as whiteboard for virtual lesson

Tags: pdf, audio, drawing

I'm a teacher and with the quarentine I need to be able to prepare my lessons for students to watch them at home. I have designed several PDFs with Beamer, with the idea of using them as whiteboards.

My original idea was to use a PDF as a presentation, and be able to draw things on it as I record my voice simultaneously. This would be the closest thing I could do to simulate a real lesson. Then I would like to export this as a video, so that the drawings do not appear "out of the blue", but the whole traces are recorded frame by frame, so students can actually see how things are being drawn, and not the finished drawing at once.

Is there any software I could use? I'm on Windows 7. I can manage to record the audio separately if you can provide me with some software to record a video where I draw on a PDF file, but if there was some software that had the recording feature built-in, it would be even better.

Comment: If you are on recent Windows 10, then there is a built in recorder, as part of the Xbox/games toolbar. https://betanews.com/2019/01/14/windows-10-screen-recorder-ultility/ Just open the PDF in your favourite PDF reader+annotater software and start recording. If you are not on windows 10,  please update your question to clarify your OS.

Comment: @Ryan I'm on Windows 7. I've updated the OP, thanks.

Comment: I would suggest VLC then, to record your screen. Its a bit awkward, but here is a guide. https://pctonic.net/use-vlc-as-a-screen-recording-tool/